# Font size in Picker control in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I am surprised to see that Picker control does not have font size property to set font size. I had a need to set font size for picker control. Kindly suggest how do I set font size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlaying scrollable `Xamarin.Form` [Picker](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/) list is handled by native controls such as iOS `UIPickerView`, Android's `DatePicker`|`TimePicker`, ... and access to these controls are **internal** to the `PickerRender` class.

You can create custom renderers for each of your targeted platforms and create custom views for each of them.

Example:

On iOS you would need to create a custom `UIPickerView` class and override the `ViewFor` method and return a `UILabel` for each row that has your custom font attributes assigned.

On Android, you would create the standard picker, say a `DatePicker`, and do a `FindViewById` to access the various `EditText`s that make up that picker and assign the `TextSize` property to each with your custom font size.

Comment: Is there a way I can use xaamrin forms control and extent it limited to PCL code only?

Comment: @RaviKanasagra You could "create" a Picker-style dialog out of `Xamarin.Forms` views/controls (a composite view of multiple Forms controls) and use that, otherwise you would need to code custom renderers for each platform.